# Obsolete test case (or test case of removed feature)

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

What to do with obsolete test case (or test case of removed feature)?
We are using VSS in our project. Hundreds of test cases are there.

Suppose some features are removed from application in current version but the test cases are still there in VSS.

Should we remove these test cases from VSS as pertaining features are removed from application? Should we keep it in different folder named 'Obsolete feature test case' in 'VSS', so that if require we can re - use it in future?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using a versioning system like Git or Subversion.

So if you have pushed your tests on the server, you can easily remove the obsolete tests now and if you need them in the future, you can get those tests back thanks to your versioning system.

It permits to have a clean repository and a clean structure on your computer without losing some obsoletes code.

Comment: Hi Pierre

We are using VSS.

Comment: @Mfs_Dheeraj As VSS is a [SCM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_Code_Management), you can still do what I suggested to you, that is, remove those tests in the future version as you can go back on older commit if you need. But you should remember that VSS is oriented for *small development projects*.

Answer (score 0):

We are using VSS.

When any test case is in SVN or VSS it is safe. We can take it from anywhere anytime. But if we keep it on our local machine, there is a chance that we can lose it (might be system crash, might be deletion of file while clean up process.....).

So it looks safe and better to create a folder and keep all the obsolete test case in VSS.